# I want to make list of characters to display in threes

Tags: javascript, java

I want to make list of characters to display in threes and no one should appear more than 3 times. Example if I have ABCDEF they should display in this format, ABC,DCA,CDB,FAE,EDB, EF, F.
both in Java Its relevant to my Studies please.
I get chucked somewhere very far compare to the ones i have being seeing so far.
The Following was my attempt

Comment: *Both Java or JavaScript Its relevant to my Studies* -- First, we do not write code for people for their homework. If you want to make something, attempt it yourself first then ask here about a specific problem. And I don't see how it's possible that homework has to do with both Java and JavaScript which are completely different.

Comment: Thank You. its really on java that I need it most. but while I said in both is because  am  learning both at this time. while I couldn't attempt is because am a novice but wish to  be like one of you out there.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class TenK {
public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner man = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the characters: ");
        char hug=man.nextchar();
}
}

Comment: I'm sure you've already been told this but what you are trying to do is called string permutations. Google **'String Permutations with Java'**. You'll be surprised with what comes up. The first thing you need to learn in either Java or JavaScript (two completely different languages) is how to put in some form of effort. Try to master one to at least some degree before attempting the other. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [a sample](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/), change it to solve your problem.

```
// Java program to print all combination of size r in an array of size n
import java.io.*;

class Permutation {

    /* arr[]  ---> Input Array
    data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination
    start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[]
    index  ---> Current index in data[]
    r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
    static void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start,
                                int end, int index, int r)
    {
        // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
        if (index == r)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
                System.out.print(data[j]+" ");
            System.out.println("");
            return;
        }

        // replace index with all possible elements. The condition
        // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element
        // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
        // at remaining positions
        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
        {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
        }
    }

    // The main function that prints all combinations of size r
    // in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil()
    static void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r)
    {
        // A temporary array to store all combination one by one
        int data[]=new int[r];

        // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]'
        combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
    }

    /*Driver function to check for above function*/
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int r = 3;
        int n = arr.length;
        printCombination(arr, n, r);
    }
}

/* This code is contributed by Devesh Agrawal */
```

or [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/)

```
// Java program to print all permutations of a
// given string.
public class Permutation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "ABC";
        int n = str.length();
        Permutation permutation = new Permutation();
        permutation.permute(str, 0, n-1);
    }

    /**
     * permutation function
     * @param str string to calculate permutation for
     * @param l starting index
     * @param r end index
     */
    private void permute(String str, int l, int r)
    {
        if (l == r)
            System.out.println(str);
        else
        {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
            {
                str = swap(str,l,i);
                permute(str, l+1, r);
                str = swap(str,l,i);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap Characters at position
     * @param a string value
     * @param i position 1
     * @param j position 2
     * @return swapped string
     */
    public String swap(String a, int i, int j)
    {
        char temp;
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
        temp = charArray[i] ;
        charArray[i] = charArray[j];
        charArray[j] = temp;
        return String.valueOf(charArray);
    }

}

// This code is contributed by Mihir Joshi
```